# What does an arrow function to another arrow function mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

In the following function, where does dispatch come from and what is the flow of control?

```
export const getContacts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_CONTACTS,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
```

I understand basic arrow functions, but what actually happens when I call getContacts(). Since I am not passing in anything, where does dispatch come from? Does this come from thunk? I did not import thunk into this file which is why I am confused. This is the whole file:

```
import { GET_CONTACTS, ADD_CONTACT, DELETE_CONTACT } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

// the following returns the objects that we want to push to the dispatch in contactRedcuer
export const getContacts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_CONTACTS,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does an arrow function to another arrow function mean in Javascript?

That the first arrow function has the second one as a return value.

If you don't pass arguments to the first one (as in this case) to form a closure, it isn't usually a useful thing to do.

> I understand basic arrow functions, but what actually happens when I call getContacts(). Since I am not passing in anything, where does dispatch come from?

`dispatch` comes when the returned function is called, which doesn't happen in the code you've shared.

---

```js
const first = (argument_to_first) => 
    (argument_to_second) => console.log({
      argument_to_first,
      argument_to_second
    });

const second = first("Hello");

second("Goodbye");
```